# Getting the earliest entry of a duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling with basic SQL. What I have is the following TICKET table

```
-----------------------
|        TICKET       |
-----------------------
|id | date     | team |
-----------------------
| 1 |22/07/2016|   A  |
| 2 |24/07/2016|   B  |
| 3 |24/07/2016|   B  |
| 1 |23/07/2016|   C  |
| 4 |25/07/2016|   A  |
| 5 |26/07/2016|   A  |
| 5 |27/07/2016|   B  |
-----------------------
```

Sometimes, after a day or two, tickets can be affected to another team (see exemple above, ticket 1 swithes from team A to team C). What I need is a list of all tickets that were originaly meant to team A (i.e. - same id, but different team ; team  A being the earliest)

I am not so sure about what I already have for the "switched team part" :

```
SELECT id, date, team
FROM TICKET
WHERE (
    id IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM TICKET
        WHERE (team = 'B' OR team = 'C')
    )
)
AND team = 'A'
```

Should I put an ORDER BY date as well as a GROUP BY clause somewhere? Isn't there an better solution?

Comment: what is your PK?? there's nothing unique in your DB.. even your ident is not an ident?

Comment: Can you add what lines you want to get as a result? I see at least 3 different possible interpretations (and thus possible results) of your sentence.

Comment: I guess `(id, date)` has to be the pk ("after a day or two, ...")

Comment: Add the expected result! (Table format.)

Comment: @Solarflare would still be a really bad table-design. if the ticket goes one day at 7am to team A and they move it the same day at 9pm to team B they're totally f....

Comment: Dates are stored using a date data type, right? I assume you just wrote it that way to confuse us.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger I agree, if they can move a ticket the same date, it cannot work; if they can only move a ticket "after a day or two...", it is fine (and actually enforces that "not at the same day"-rule).

Comment: The table I gave is a simplified version of what I currently work on, sorry for all these confusions I guess. The date field are indeed using the date data type. Anyway, @StanislavL's solution works like a charm for me. Thank you all for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct t.id
from ticket t
     inner join ticket t1 on t.id=t1.id and t1.team<>'A' and t.date<t1.date
where
    t.team='A'
```